# Android Studio 2.2.3 - Import the DecimalFormat class Java Code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-studio-2.2

I am quite confused when I get this error within my MainActivity.java code inside Android Studio. I need to import the DecimalFormat class so I can establish a currency format.  How do I resolve this?

**Picture of error:**

[image: Image 1]

**Picture of suggested fixes:**

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out my own question. By going to Gradle Scripts and then to build.gradle(Module:app) and then changing my minSdkVersion from 15 to 24, it worked.